# Problem with modules java "Module 'mp3player' reads package 'javafx.animation' from both 'javafx.graphics' and 'javafx.graphics'"

Tags: java, macos, javafx, dependencies

I tried to make mp3player in maven, then download dependency javafx-graphics from mvnrepos

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And I have problem in module:
"Module 'mp3player' reads package 'javafx.animation' from both 'javafx.graphics' and 'javafx.graphics'"

I work on MacOs, InteliJ, can someone help me? Screenshots from InteliJ:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqK8H.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvvJC.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuLD2.png)

Comment: What JDK are you using? Not just the version, but also where did you download it from?

Comment: This JDK : Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    14.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 14.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

From https://www.oracle.com/pl/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

If you can help, please tell me how to uninstall it and install good jdk :) Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Was wondering if you were using a JDK that already included JavaFX, but Oracle's distribution does not include JavaFX. Though I find your error strange in the first place. I would expect some sort of "duplicate modules found" error rather than a split-package error. Is it possible to provide a [mre] (in the question itself, as properly formatted text)?

Answer (score 0):

go to open module settings -> dependencies and check if you have the same dependencies as in the following image:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFE7W.png)

otherwise go to file-> Invalidate Caches and restarting and click invalidate and restart

Comment: still i have the same problem.. :(